# Tricky Curved Hardsurface, suggestions? (mandalorian helmet)

Tags: modeling, geometry

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to model this part of the mandolorian hemlet without sculpting.

any help, tips, references is greatly appreciated!

[image: Tricky Helmet Geometry!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion it would help if you had a side view, and use both images as background.

Begin with the right side, build a very simple topology that follows the lines. Switch to front view, move the vertices one by one to make them fit to this new view.

Fill the faces, add edge loops to sharp the angles.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what i needed! Thanks for an amazing detailed answer with an example! :D