# Remove Unwanted Edge Loops

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

[image][image]

I'm modelling a helmet and one of the pieces needs sharp edges. The problem is that the edge loop continues onto a part of the mesh that needs to stay smooth/curved. I'm unsure of how to edit the mesh to fix this whilst maintaining good topology, so any help on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). As expected, @Moonboots  [has you covered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179570/78972)

Comment: I saw that post whilst trying to solve the problem, but the images are taken from too far from the mesh to tell how they fixed the issue, that's why I posted a new question :)

Comment: Just compare your topology with the answer :). Your edges are very close together which causes the crease. Moonboots has the edges more spread out :).

Comment: ah, now I see what they did, thanks for the response :)