# How can I fill the inside of this helmet?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender and I have this helmet model that I want to fill the inside of, but I'm not sure how to do it or if it's even possible. I've tried searching for videos or guides but nothing seems to cover what I'm looking for.

As you can see it's quite a complex model with lots of curves and angles so not very straightforward (at least to me).

Also if possible I'd like to create a separate piece that follows the profile of the Visor and would be able to sit behind it.

I basically want to make this into a solid object.

[image: Bottom of helmet]

[image: Bottom (angled)]

[image: Front]

[image: Vertices]

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "fill the inside of"? A helmet is hollow by definition

Comment: I want to eventually print it at 1/6 scale, so I want it to be a solid object and not a hollow wearable helmet.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179565/tricky-curved-hardsurface-suggestions-mandalorian-helmet

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: Recommend reducing the amount of vertices in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

So my answer works better if you've kept a low-poly version. Always keep a low-poly version somewhere, before applying the *Subdivision Surface*.

You can:

- Select all the external vertices + the small inner extrusions:

[image]

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to invert the selection:

[image]

- Delete:

[image]

- Fill the gaps, with *Grid Fill* if possible:

[image]

- For the bottom, extrude inwards and close the shape:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The model has a lot of vertices and not all of them get picked up in the selection window, is there a quicker/more efficient way to select all of the external verticles. I've updated the original post with a screenshot of them.

Comment: no magic trick as far as I know, but it shouldn't be too hard to select manually, but you shouldn't go high-poly if you plan to edit your object, instead, keep the Subdivision Surface modifier, work on your mesh, then at the end when you are satisfied, make a copy of the object to keep a low-poly version somewhere, and apply the modifier to get a high-poly version. TLTR: You should have kept a low-poly.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't make the model myself just looking to use it for something. Thanks for the tips though.