# How to harden edges using subsurface modifier on corners (Mandalorian helmet)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to model a helmet using subsurface modifier, there is a section where the corners are projecting causing a bevel. I have mean crease the entire border section which didn't help. And also tried some perimeter around the mesh to see if that would make the corners more square but its ruining the topology. If I start adding more loops ( vertical & Horizontally) again its deforming the shape of the helmet. How can I get the corners more like the reference image?

I've also included the Blend file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topology gives a good result, it just needs a bit of adjustments at the end (like flatten on custom axis) to avoid pinching. I didn't try to fix the rest of the topology (but [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179565/tricky-curved-hardsurface-suggestions-mandalorian-helmet) is an answer that might help).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a closer screen shot from the topology, and share a few angles how the loops are going around the mesh, thank you.

Comment: sure, I've edited

Comment: Appreciate it!!!

Comment: are you following some kind of courses? It looks like there has been a lot of mandalorian helmets these last months  ;)

Comment: Good thought, I found a tutorial, so it'll give me a better perspective how its actually modelled. I was trying to freestyle and see how far I could get after 1 year of Blender 3D practice. But since I found this video here, I'm keen to see how its done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lw2fXEpCbHo&list=UU5Xzr_xXz9IoeJU2brDa6LA&index=2

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [edge split modifier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pS-BZk-1IE). Essentially, the modifier splits edges so they are no longer connected, which allows you to keep some of the hard edges. You can merge the vertices later in edit mode.